# longdivision package: missing number, treated as zero and divisor is too large errors

Tags: math-mode, longdivision

I wrote a document months ago in which I used the longdivision package to do some calculations such as 999/12.  At the time, the document compiled properly.  However, it no longer compiles properly.  I get four errors when I try to compile the code below using TeXMaker (from which I have drawn the error messages) or TeXStudio:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.<to be read again>\__int_eval_end: \[\intlongdivision{999}{12}
```

```
! Package longdivision Error: Divisor '12' is too large (on line 6). It has 2(longdivision) digits, but divisors can be at most 9 digits(longdivision) long.Type <return> to continue.... \[\intlongdivision{999}{12}
```

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.<to be read again>\__int_eval_end: \[\intlongdivision{999}{12}
```

```
! Package longdivision Error: Divisor '12' is too large (on line 9). It has 2(longdivision) digits, but divisors can be at most 9 digits(longdivision) long.Type <return> to continue.... \[\intlongdivision{999}{12}
```

The second error strikes me as bizarre since 2 < 9.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{longdivision}

\begin{document}
\[\longdivision{999}{12}\]

\[\intlongdivision{999}{12}\]
\end{document}
```

I also get the same error when I load the packages calc and/or mathtools before loading the package longdivision.

Any tips on how to fix this error would be appreciated.

**Update:** Given SandyG's feedback, I tried compiling this code in Overleaf, where it works.  However, I cannot compile this code on my Linux Mint 21 operating system, where I am using TeXStudio and have TexLive installed.

**Update:**  David Carlisle requested that I add the full log file, which I have placed below.

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=latex 2022.8.24)  9 DEC 2022 05:37
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**long_division_examples.tex
(./long_division_examples.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-01-21>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count185
\c@section=\count186
\c@subsection=\count187
\c@subsubsection=\count188
\c@paragraph=\count189
\c@subparagraph=\count190
\c@figure=\count191
\c@table=\count192
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen138
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathtools/mathtools.sty
Package: mathtools 2021/02/02 v1.28 mathematical typesetting tools

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks16
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty
Package: calc 2017/05/25 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
\calc@Acount=\count193
\calc@Bcount=\count194
\calc@Adimen=\dimen139
\calc@Bdimen=\dimen140
\calc@Askip=\skip49
\calc@Bskip=\skip50
LaTeX Info: Redefining \setlength on input line 80.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \addtolength on input line 81.
\calc@Ccount=\count195
\calc@Cskip=\skip51
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathtools/mhsetup.sty
Package: mhsetup 2021/03/18 v1.4 programming setup (MH)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2021/10/15 v2.17l AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip52

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2021/08/26 v2.01 AMS text

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks17
\ex@=\dimen141
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen142
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 2021/08/26 v2.02 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count196
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 234.
\uproot@=\count197
\leftroot@=\count198
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 399.
\classnum@=\count199
\DOTSCASE@=\count266
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 496.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 499.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 620.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box50
\strutbox@=\box51
\big@size=\dimen143
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 743.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 744.
\macc@depth=\count267
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count268
\dotsspace@=\muskip16
\c@parentequation=\count269
\dspbrk@lvl=\count270
\tag@help=\toks18
\row@=\count271
\column@=\count272
\maxfields@=\count273
\andhelp@=\toks19
\eqnshift@=\dimen144
\alignsep@=\dimen145
\tagshift@=\dimen146
\tagwidth@=\dimen147
\totwidth@=\dimen148
\lineht@=\dimen149
\@envbody=\toks20
\multlinegap=\skip53
\multlinetaggap=\skip54
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks21
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2938.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2939.
)
\g_MT_multlinerow_int=\count274
\l_MT_multwidth_dim=\dimen150
\origjot=\skip55
\l_MT_shortvdotswithinadjustabove_dim=\dimen151
\l_MT_shortvdotswithinadjustbelow_dim=\dimen152
\l_MT_above_intertext_sep=\dimen153
\l_MT_below_intertext_sep=\dimen154
\l_MT_above_shortintertext_sep=\dimen155
\l_MT_below_shortintertext_sep=\dimen156
\xmathstrut@box=\box52
\xmathstrut@dim=\dimen157
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks22
\pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen158
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen159

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-lists.t
ex)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
\pgfutil@abb=\box53
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex)
Package: pgfrcs 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
))
Package: pgf 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2021/09/16 v1.2d Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2021/03/04 v1.4d Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2021/08/11 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: dvips.def on input line 107.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/dvips.def
File: dvips.def 2017/06/20 v3.1d Graphics/color driver for dvips
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen160
\Gin@req@width=\dimen161
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
Package: pgfsys 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks23
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks24

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.code.t
ex
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks25
))
\pgf@x=\dimen162
\pgf@y=\dimen163
\pgf@xa=\dimen164
\pgf@ya=\dimen165
\pgf@xb=\dimen166
\pgf@yb=\dimen167
\pgf@xc=\dimen168
\pgf@yc=\dimen169
\pgf@xd=\dimen170
\pgf@yd=\dimen171
\w@pgf@writea=\write3
\r@pgf@reada=\read2
\c@pgf@counta=\count275
\c@pgf@countb=\count276
\c@pgf@countc=\count277
\c@pgf@countd=\count278
\t@pgf@toka=\toks26
\t@pgf@tokb=\toks27
\t@pgf@tokc=\toks28
\pgf@sys@id@count=\count279
 (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg
File: pgf.cfg 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
)
Driver file for pgf: pgfsys-dvips.def

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-dvips.def
File: pgfsys-dvips.def 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-postsc
ript.def
File: pgfsys-common-postscript.def 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgf@objectcount=\count280
)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.code.
tex
File: pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgfsyssoftpath@smallbuffer@items=\count281
\pgfsyssoftpath@bigbuffer@items=\count282
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.code.
tex
File: pgfsysprotocol.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2021/10/31 v2.13 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: dvips.def on input line 227.
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1352.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1372.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1373.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1374.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1375.
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
Package: pgfcore 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen172
\pgfmath@count=\count283
\pgfmath@box=\box54
\pgfmath@toks=\toks29
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks30
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks31
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code
.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonomet
ric.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison
.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.
tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code
.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.
tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integerari
thmetics.code.tex)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count284
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfint.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.code.te
x
File: pgfcorepoints.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgf@picminx=\dimen173
\pgf@picmaxx=\dimen174
\pgf@picminy=\dimen175
\pgf@picmaxy=\dimen176
\pgf@pathminx=\dimen177
\pgf@pathmaxx=\dimen178
\pgf@pathminy=\dimen179
\pgf@pathmaxy=\dimen180
\pgf@xx=\dimen181
\pgf@xy=\dimen182
\pgf@yx=\dimen183
\pgf@yy=\dimen184
\pgf@zx=\dimen185
\pgf@zy=\dimen186
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconstruct.
code.tex
File: pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgf@path@lastx=\dimen187
\pgf@path@lasty=\dimen188
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage.code
.tex
File: pgfcorepathusage.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgf@shorten@end@additional=\dimen189
\pgf@shorten@start@additional=\dimen190
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.code.te
x
File: pgfcorescopes.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgfpic=\box55
\pgf@hbox=\box56
\pgf@layerbox@main=\box57
\pgf@picture@serial@count=\count285
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicstate.c
ode.tex
File: pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgflinewidth=\dimen191
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformation
s.code.tex
File: pgfcoretransformations.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgf@pt@x=\dimen192
\pgf@pt@y=\dimen193
\pgf@pt@temp=\dimen194
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.code.tex
File: pgfcorequick.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.code.t
ex
File: pgfcoreobjects.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathprocessing
.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.te
x
File: pgfcorearrows.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgfarrowsep=\dimen195
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex
File: pgfcoreshade.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgf@max=\dimen196
\pgf@sys@shading@range@num=\count286
\pgf@shadingcount=\count287
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.code.tex
File: pgfcoreimage.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.code.
tex
File: pgfcoreexternal.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgfexternal@startupbox=\box58
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.code.te
x
File: pgfcorelayers.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransparency.c
ode.tex
File: pgfcoretransparency.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.code.
tex
File: pgfcorepatterns.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorerdf.code.tex
File: pgfcorerdf.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex
File: pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgfnodeparttextbox=\box59
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.tex
File: pgfmoduleplot.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-0-65
.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-0-65 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgf@nodesepstart=\dimen197
\pgf@nodesepend=\dimen198
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-1-18
.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-1-18 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
Package: pgffor 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)
\pgffor@iter=\dimen199
\pgffor@skip=\dimen256
\pgffor@stack=\toks32
\pgffor@toks=\toks33
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex
Package: tikz 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothandlers
.code.tex
File: pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgf@plot@mark@count=\count288
\pgfplotmarksize=\dimen257
)
\tikz@lastx=\dimen258
\tikz@lasty=\dimen259
\tikz@lastxsaved=\dimen260
\tikz@lastysaved=\dimen261
\tikz@lastmovetox=\dimen262
\tikz@lastmovetoy=\dimen263
\tikzleveldistance=\dimen264
\tikzsiblingdistance=\dimen265
\tikz@figbox=\box60
\tikz@figbox@bg=\box61
\tikz@tempbox=\box62
\tikz@tempbox@bg=\box63
\tikztreelevel=\count289
\tikznumberofchildren=\count290
\tikznumberofcurrentchild=\count291
\tikz@fig@count=\count292

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.code.tex
File: pgfmodulematrix.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgfmatrixcurrentrow=\count293
\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn=\count294
\pgf@matrix@numberofcolumns=\count295
)
\tikz@expandcount=\count296

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tik
zlibrarytopaths.code.tex
File: tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
))) (./longdivision.sty
Package: longdivision 

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2022-01-21 L3 programming layer (loader) 

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-dvips.def
File: l3backend-dvips.def 2022-01-12 L3 backend support: dvips
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box64
\g__pdf_backend_object_int=\count297
\l__pdf_backend_content_box=\box65
\l__pdf_backend_model_box=\box66
\g__pdf_backend_annotation_int=\count298
\g__pdf_backend_link_int=\count299
\g__pdf_backend_link_sf_int=\count300
))
Package: xparse 2022-01-12 L3 Experimental document command parser
)
\l__longdiv_linkedlist_length_int=\count301
\l__longdiv_temp_int=\count302
\l__longdiv_quotient_int=\count303
\l__longdiv_position_int=\count304
\l__longdiv_point_digit_int=\count305
\g__longdiv_temp_dim=\dimen266
\l__longdiv_extra_digits_int=\count306
\l__longdiv_max_extra_digits_int=\count307
\l__longdiv_display_divisions_int=\count308
\c__longdiv_digitwidth_dim=\dimen267
\c__longdiv_pointwidth_dim=\dimen268
\l__longdiv_tempwidth_dim=\dimen269
)
(./long_division_examples.aux)
\openout1 = `long_division_examples.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \__int_eval_end: 
l.7 \[\longdivision{999}{12}
                            \]
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)


! Package longdivision Error: Divisor '12' is too large (on line 7). It has 2
(longdivision)                digits, but divisors can be at most 9 digits
(longdivision)                long.

Type <return> to continue.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 \[\longdivision{999}{12}
                            \]

LaTeX does not know anything more about this error, sorry.

Try typing <return> to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type X <return> to quit.


! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \__int_eval_end: 
l.9 \[\intlongdivision{999}{12}
                               \]
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)


! Package longdivision Error: Divisor '12' is too large (on line 9). It has 2
(longdivision)                digits, but divisors can be at most 9 digits
(longdivision)                long.

Type <return> to continue.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.9 \[\intlongdivision{999}{12}
                               \]

LaTeX does not know anything more about this error, sorry.

Try typing <return> to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type X <return> to quit.


[1

] (./long_division_examples.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 12767 strings out of 478288
 265387 string characters out of 5849315
 556525 words of memory out of 5000000
 30775 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 469713 words of font info for 30 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 100i,5n,104p,428b,131s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

Output written on long_division_examples.dvi (1 page, 10696 bytes).
```

Comment: Just came across this. I cannot recreate the problem—your code compiles correctly for me.

Comment: @SandyG  Thanks for your feedback.  I can compile this properly in Overleaf.  However, it does not compile properly on my Linux Mint 21 operating system.

Comment: Your document works without error in texlive 2020, 2021 and 2022 pdflatex. Show the full log you get for that file.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have added the error log.  I am using pdflatex.  Thank you for your attention.

Comment: no, add the full log so it shows the paths to all packages used. The specific errors are just arbitrary, you are (somewhere) loading the wrong code.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  I have added the log file.

Comment: bingo: `(./longdivision.sty`  you are using  a local `longdivision.sty` not the one we are using, from texlive.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That solved the problem.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your log shows

```
(./longdivision.sty
```

So you are using a local `longdivision.sty` not the one from texlive, which for you would be

```
(/usr/local/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/longdivision/longdivision.sty
```

if you delete (or rename) the local file, the document should run without error.